Book where people in a future society escape to an island to be free
for the life of me I cannot remember this book.  the main character lived in some sort of futuristic society where the government controls the information they know.  he is approached by this secret group of people that consisted of only a handful of people.  they met in what i think i remember as the ministry of history where they would smoke, read books that were  banned/supposed to be destroyed, learned dead languages and did things that were socially unacceptable.  they had heard there was this island where people could live freely and eventually discovered a map in this ministry they met in where the location of the island was covered up physically when they removed it from its frame.  they traveled to this island and realized it wasnt quite what they were expecting but it was real living.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

This Perfect Day by Ira Levin? People have to take daily shots, which suppress their emotions.

@sueelleker, I  think you've got it, there is a scene in "this perfect day"where the "underground" meet in a museum and try to enact the "before unification" pleasures.

That's definitely it, @sueelleker - go ahead and write it up as an answer.

This Perfect Day by Ira Levin.
A central computer called "UniComp" manages everything humans do. People have to take monthly shots to suppress their emotions. The man is called "Chip" (a nickname given to him by his grandfather; people only have one of four official names) One of the rebel women is nicknamed "Lilac".

Thank Christ, Marx, Wood and Wei, who led us to this Perfect Day.
